# how would i convert this into powershell?

Tags: powershell, startup, file-conversion

```
on error resume next                                             'allows the script to continue if an error occurs.
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")             'creates scripting object
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("wscript.Network")                 'creates an object for network scripting

'the next section maps network drives if they don't already exist

If Not fso.DriveExists("z") Then                                 'checks for an existing drive x
  objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "z:", "\\ptfg-fs-005p\204ISShare"         'maps network drive x to \\108wg-fs-05\204is
End If

If Not fso.DriveExists("Y") Then                                 'repeat of above for other drive letters
  objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "Y:", "\\108arw-fs-02\global"
End If

If Not fso.DriveExists("K") Then                                 'repeat of above for other drive letters
  objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "K:", "\\108arw-fs-02\apps"
End If

'the next section maps network printers

ptrName = "\\ptfg-mp-001v\204isispcl000"                          'creates a variable for the part of a printer name that is a constant
ptrs = array("3","4","5","6","7","8")
for each x in ptrs                                               'start of loop that will create the next printer
    addPtr = ptrName & x                                         'adds current number from loop to printer constant name
    objNetwork.addWindowsPrinterConnection addPtr                'adds printer
next                                                             'end of add printer loop

wScript.quit                                                     'ends script
```

Comment: By writing some code into a text editor and saving it in a file with the extension `.ps1` :-) Which part are you having trouble translating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a direct sense you can instantiate COM objects in PowerShell like:

```
$objFSO     = New-Object -ComObject "Scripting.FileSystemObject"
$objNetwork = New-Object -ComObject "wscript.Network"
```

So the same properties and methods are then available...

Note: While common in VBScript, Hungarian notation, ie `str...` or `obj...` is generally frowned upon.

Above is a direct translation, however I think in the longer term it's better to emulate the same functionality using more native PowerShell functionality.

You can use the `Test-Path` cmdlet Documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path?view=powershell-7.1) to test the presence of a drive. It will return a Boolean, so an alternative might look something like:

```
If( -not ( Test-Path 'k:' ) ) {
 # Do something
}
```

The PowerShell native way to map a drive is with the `New-PSDrive` cmdlet. Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive?view=powershell-7.1)

Example:

```
New-PSDrive -PSProvider Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem -Name K -Root "\\108arw-fs-02\apps" -Persist
```

You can declare arrays in a similar fashion:

```
$Printers = "Printer1", "Printer2" # Etc...
```

Also note the array subexpression can be used:

```
$Printers = @( "Printer1", "Printer2" ) # Etc...
```

For adding printers you can use the `Add-Printer` cmdlet, documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/printmanagement/add-printer?view=win10-ps#examples)

Example:

```
 Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\printServer\printerName
```

There are several looping constructs to choose from.  You can research them all in the PowerShell documentation, but the `ForEach` construct looks like:

```
ForEach( $Printer in $Printers) {
 # Map your printer...
}
```

Comment: does this seem correct as a final code? '$objFSO     = New-Object -ComObject "Scripting.FileSystemObject"
$objNetwork = New-Object -ComObject "wscript.Network"
If( -not ( Test-Path 'k:' ) ) {
New-PSDrive -PSProvider Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem -Name K -Root "\\108arw-fs-02\apps" -Persist
}
If( -not ( Test-Path 'Y:' ) ) {
New-PSDrive -PSProvider Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem -Name Y -Root "\\108arw-fs-02\global" -Persist
'

Comment: '}
If( -not ( Test-Path 'k:' ) ) {
New-PSDrive -PSProvider Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem -Name Z -Root "\\ptfg-fs-005p\204ISShare" -Persist
}
ForEach( $Printer in $Printers) {
Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\printServer\printerName
}'

Comment: I had to reformat it. At a glance it looks like it would work, but I can't test something this specific for you.  In retrospect I wish I had put the `New-PSDrive` & `Add-Printer` commands in the script blocks. But certainly from what you posted you got the point.  If I have time I'll try to update the answer.